# Car Front Left Woofer Not Working, But Tweeter does. (Peugeot 406 2001)

Tags: audio, speakers

The wires on woofer and tweeter have the same connection to the radio tape. I have tested the continuity of the wires go to woofer using multimeter and having beep sound on both positive and negative. I have checked that the woofer is not broken. Tried to connect the woofer to the tweeter wires and it worked. But connecting the tweeter to the woofer wire then it not worked.

[image: Key to wiring diagram]

[image: Wiring diagram of audio system]

The speaker that has no sound is no. 197

Speakers, head unit, and wiring are original and standard. It worked a few days ago.

I also tested the continuity between wire goes to tweeter and wire goes to woofer and it beeping on my multimeter.

Update after suggested to check the ohms. So pick up the multimeter and set the setting to 200:

Checked the ohms of cable resulting:
Ba to Gr = 29.4
Vi to Rg = 04.0

I also checked the ohms between radio unit wire negative and positive toward the woofer resulting:
Negative Wire = 22.8
Positive Wire = 01.2

Update:

Checked the negative wire that has bad connection was from the car door socket/connector to the woofer..it might somewhat damaged because water or broken due to door opening/closing. The wire from tape unit to the door socket has low ohm.

Thanks to HandyHowie for the clues. It just valuable new knowledge for me to check not only the continuity but also the resistance that might make things not working.

Comment: Is this a standard figment for the car, or have you modified it?  Original speakers, original head unit and original wiring?

Comment: hi thanks for your response. Speakers, head unit, and wiring are original and standard. It worked a few days ago.

Comment: I also tested the continuity between wire goes to tweeter and wire goes to woofer and it beeping on my multimeter.

Comment: Do you have a wiring diagram for the sound system?  If so, can you share it?

Comment: Yes sir, I just attached to the post..the speaker that has no sound is no. 197..

Comment: When you - "tested the continuity between wire goes to tweeter and wire goes to woofer and it beeping on my multimeter."  Did you check 'Ba' to 'Gr' and then 'Vi' to 'Rg'?  I would suggest that you take a measurement in the ohms range of both wires and report back,  the beep function wont show a poor connection.

Comment: Yes, checked Ba-Gr, Vi-Rg having beep..Will reporting back for ohms value on my multimeter with lowest setting (200m).  Thank you sir.